# More efficient way of updating an attribute on a product, Magento

Tags: php, magento, attributes, e-commerce

Just been tasked with updating around 3k SKU's. I wrote a script that looks like this:

```
if($updates_handle) { 
    while($sku_entry=fgetcsv($updates_handle, 1024, ",")) { 

        /* get the old and new Product SKU values */
        list($old_sku, $new_sku) = $sku_entry;

        echo 'Setting: '.$old_sku.' SKU to: '.$new_sku.'<br />';

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('skuref1', $old_sku);

        $product->setSku($new_sku);

//      $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'Sku');
//      
//      $product->save();


    }
    echo "<br />DONE<br />";
}
```

The problem is, and as I have read the ->save() function takes around 3 seconds a product, I have also tried the ->saveAttribute, but that gives me an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catalog_product_entity.value_id' in 'field list'' in /var/www/website/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/website/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #1 /var/www/website/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(468): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #2 /var/www/website/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array) #3 /var/www/website/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array) #4 /var/www/website/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(799): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array) #5 /var/www/website/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mag in /var/www/website/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 234
```

Can someone explain what im doing wrong?

Comment: sku isn't an eav attribute, that's why `saveAttribute()` can't be used to save it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following, where `$productPids` is an array of product IDs.

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
    ->updateAttributes($productPids, array('sku' => 'my_sku'), 0);
```

But in your scenario, you would have to have an array of 1 product, as this is designed for mass update of the same value, not mass update of different values.

In your case, I would be inclined (although not advocated by the community) to make the change with an SQL script, it will take less than a second to execute.

Or, if you insist on sticking to the Mage API, then disable all the "Update on save" settings for all indexes, you'll drop `$product->save()` times by a significant margin, but still nowhere close to just executing a raw SQL statement.

Comment: Can we use this solution to update the categories of a product?

Comment: I have 20k products, by default all products assigned both websites in multi-store. How can I remove all products from selected one website in multi-store?

Answer (score 0):

using magento model for mass update is a very slow method.
However there is a model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Action`, that is used for mass update in magento admin. You can find its method `updateAttributes` very useful